# how to use Jqzoom with Jquery version 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, jqzoom

I need to use Jqzoom with Jquery-1.8.3 .As it supports jquery-1.6.I tried to add multiple scripts Jquery 1.8.3 and Jquery 1.6 with .noConflict function but still i get error

**TypeError: jQuery_1_6(...).jqzoom is not a function**

I could not use Jquery1.6 as my whole project is using jquery 1.8.3

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>

    <script>
    var jQuery_1_6 = $.noConflict(true);

    $(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery_1_6('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
                zoomType: 'standard',
                lens:false,
                preloadImages: false,
                alwaysOn:false,
                position:'right',
                zoomWidth: 100,  
                zoomHeight: 100,
                xOffset:30,  
                yOffset:30
            });


    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @SonalPM Your proposed edit has an extra script tag with what appears to be unrelated code.  Are you certain the OP wants you to do that?